# Correct way to support multiple authorization attributes on ASP.Net Web API 2

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

My ASP.Net Web API app created a JWT Token upon successful login.

```
public IHttpActionResult LogOn([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
    {
        var result = _service.LogOn(request);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            var token = CreateToken(request.UserName);
            return Ok(OpResult<string>.SuccessResult(token));
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

I have all controller methods decorated with an "Authorize" attribute which delegates to my TokenValidationHandler (inherits from DelegatingHandler) to validate the token in subsequent requests.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IHttpActionResult GetAccount(){ // get user details here}
```

Now I have a requirement to not let the user in unless they have created an account and verified their eMail address. So my idea is that in the first method (user login), instead of just checking result.success and issuing a token, I'd check also check if the retrieved account is eMail verified. If not I'd issue a jwt token with an additional claim "emailverified" set to false. So users hwo haven't activated their eMail can still login and get this jwt token, but the only operation they are allowed is VerifyEmail.

How do I go about implementing this VerifyEmail controller method? Ideally I want it to look like below

```
[HttpGet]
[AuthorizeEvenIfEmailNotVerified]
public IHttpActionResult GetAccount()
```

How do I implement AuthorizeEvenIfEmailNotVerified ? Is it another handler that inherits from DelegatingHandler ? But if I have two such handlers (my existing handelr for the regular authorize and this new one), then how does the ASP.Net engine know which handler to send [Authorize] attribute to and which to send [AuthorizeEvenIfEmailNotVerified] to ?
Or should I be using an AuthenticationFilter?
But in that case, it seems weird that I have two attributes doing pretty much the same thing (one authenticating a verified user and the other authenticating a non verified user). yet one of those is implemented via [Authorize] backed by handler inheriting DelegatingHandler whereas the other is implemented via an attribute backed by an AuthenticationFilter?

Or am I going about this the wrong way? For the record I'd prefer to keep the project free of any MVC related libraries unless absolutely needed. Also this is .Net Framework 4.7 project.

Comment: Have a read of this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters#setting-an-authentication-filter

Comment: Also the issuer of the token should "worry" if email is confirmed. Maybe add a scope to the jwt like ValidEmail that way your MVC app can check the token with adding out extra calls to your db.

Comment: Yes the issuer worries if the eMail is confirmed. That is the part where I say

 "instead of just checking result.success and issuing a token, I'd check also check if the retrieved account is eMail verified. If not I'd issue a jwt token with an additional claim "emailverified" set to false"

Comment: My question is how do I implement a method like verifyemail or resendverification both of which I want to allow only if the request carries this token I issued. Obviously I can't mark them with "[Authorize]" because that would lead to my fully verified login handler handling the request which is not what I want. I want these methods to be decorated with an attribute which calls an alternate tokenhandler which verifies that the token is valid and has claim "emailverified" set to false"

Answer (score 0):

Probably Roles will be easiest solution. Generate token with relevant claim:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Verified")); //verified email
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "NotVerified")); //not verified email
```

Next add attribute to controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles="NotVerified")]
```